# How can I make it where I automatically move in a certain direction (Purpose is for wall jump)

Tags: game-maker, gml

I am trying to add a wall jump to my game and am struggling with the horizontal momentum, where it just teleports to the location instead of it being a smooth arc.

```
var move = key_right - key_left;

//horizontal collision
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,oWall)) {
    while (!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp),y,oWall)) {
        x = x + sign(hsp);
    }
    hsp = 0;
    if (!place_meeting(x,y+vsp,oWall)) {
    walltouch = true;
    }
}
else {
walltouch = false;
}

//vertical collision
if (place_meeting(x,y+vsp,oWall)) {
    while (!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),oWall)) {
    y = y + sign(vsp);
    }
    vsp = 0;
    inair = false;
}
else  {
inair = true;
}

//wall jump
if (inair) && (walltouch) && (key_jump) {
vsp = -15;  //vertical momentum
hsp = -30 * move;  // horizontal momentum
}
```

Comment: I think I'm missing the part where `hsp` and `vsp` is used for moving the object, here it's only set to a value, and used to collide properly with the wall.